# Keword this - a class member reffering to itself

Tags: c++, this

Concering syntax in c++

The keyword **this** is a pointer to the object (class) itself and putting a * ahead of this is the same as derefferencing the pointer.

So let say the class has a private member

```
 private:
 int a = 10;
```

And I create the following syntax:

```
 (*this).a = obj.a;
```

*Could be used for instance when overloading the "=" operator*

It looks abit strange because it seems that the class member "a" is referring to itself - ***but its a valid syntax!!!***

Then my question is - **if** that statement is valid - **why** could one not write it in the following manner:

```
 obj.a = obj.a;
```

???

I get the following error in **Eclipse**:

*assignment ti itself*

Comment: `obj.a = obj.a` is self assignment. There is nothing magic about it , it's like trying to move the water from one glass to the same glass :). The compiler will not complain if you will try to do that.

Comment: is that showing a error or a warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing illegal about self-assignment, strictly speaking. Eclipse is simply warning you because it's a silly thing to do. What it should definitely *not* be doing is erroring, because it's not an error. In this case, you're just running up against the limitations of whatever static analyzer Eclipse is using which can't figure out whether or not it's the same thing, whereas `obj.a` is clearly the same thing as `obj.a`.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj.a = obj.a;
```

Eclipse is warning you about about an obvious self-assignment.

```
(*this).a = obj.a;
```

Usually, `*this` is not the same instance as `obj`, and if it is, this may only become apparent at runtime. So Eclipse's static analyzer does not emit a warning in this case.

Note also that you don't need `this`:

```
a = obj.a;
```

would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it that way. It's valid C++.

Eclipse is just pointing out that it's a useless thing to do. Auto-detecting this for arbitrary expressions such as `*(this).a` is just a little beyond its capabilities. This is because it cannot physically be done for all programs.

For example:

```
void T::foo(T& other)
{
   T* ptr = nullptr;
   if (rand())
      ptr = this;
   else
      ptr = &other;

   T& obj = *ptr;
   this->a = obj.a; // cannot be optimised out
}
```

But, in other cases, theoretically a full C++ parsing engine could do it just like your compiler's optimiser could.

For example:

```
void T::foo()
{
   T& obj = *this;
   this->a = obj.a; // can easily be optimised out
}
```

There is little point in writing code in an IDE/intellisense to try to figure these cases out; it's just not worth it. So it doesn't try.

Comment: @jogojapan: Well, yes, in such a case it would be impossible. But there is a subset of scenarios where it would not be, just the same as the compiler's optimiser would be able to spot those scenarios. For example, `T& obj = *this; this->a = obj.a;`